# Connect to Heroku Postgres - server does not support SSL connections

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, ssl, heroku

I have been following the [official Heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#provision-a-database) to set up a Postgres db which appears to have gone well as I can access and check my table exists.

However, I cannot seem to access this DB via the method and code that they also provide... I am receiving the common error:

```
The server does not support SSL connections
```

Am I missing something drastic within my code?

```
const express = require('express');
const {Pool} = require('pg');

const DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://postgres:<Password>@localhost:5432/<App-Name>';
const PORT = '8080';
const TABLE_NAME = <table-name>;

const db = new Pool({
    connectionString: DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: true
    }
});

express()
    .use(express.static(__dirname))
    .set('view engine', 'ejs')
    .get('/', (req, res) => res.send('hello world'))
    .get('/db', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const client = await db.connect();
            const result = await client.query('SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME');
            res.send(result);
            client.release();
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.send("Error " + err);
        }
    })
    .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port: ${PORT}`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also used `pg` for Postgres and it workes with this code:

```js
    pool = new Pool({
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        ssl: true,
    });
```

Tip: If you want to work both on heroku and local (for testing), a little snippet:

```js
// if on heroku
if (process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
    pool = new Pool({
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        ssl: true,
    });
} else {
// if on local
    pool = new Pool({
        user: process.env.D_user,
        password: process.env.D_password,
        port: process.env.D_pport,
        host: process.env.D_host,
        database: process.env.D_database
    });
}
```

PS The local `process.env` are manually created by `python-dotenv`

Comment: Thanks for the advice :-) Setting `SSL: true` however brings up the returned message `{"code":"DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT"}`.

Comment: I returned SSL back to using `rejectUnauthorized: true` but now Heroku is throwing: `{"length":108,"name":"error","severity":"ERROR","code":"42P01","position":"15","file":"parse_relation.c","line":"1194","routine":"parserOpenTable"}`... This seems to say that table is undefined.... strange

Comment: Ah I think I know the reason why it's undefined! I had only specified the `TABLE_NAME` for local `process.env.TABLE_NAME`! Forgive me stupidness XD